# listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio

I'm trying to connect the local Oracle database using Visual Studio. Here is the screenshot I'm working on. I don't know what to enter for Database service name. Can you tell me what to write for service name for localhost? Thanks.
 [image]

Comment: Enter your local Oracle service instance name.

Comment: You had to enter the DB name when you created the database.

Comment: [this](https://www.youtube.com/user/OracleDOTNETTeam) will help you, scip ODAC installation, see from 5 min.